# I the have country boundaries. How do I fill in with dots?

Tags: geometry, maps, geospatial

I got my country lat/long boundaries from koordinates.com. Now I want to fill in the interior with dots.

Since the file I have is KML, I was thinking of converting the coordinates to cartesian using the NetTopologySuite.

I do not want a polygon overlay. I want to generate dots/coordinates for the polygons interior - ideally at a density of my choosing.

I have seen algorithms like this one, http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_fill/. Is there a library that will do this for me? Alternatively, can someone share code?

Ultimately, I will convert the dot coordinates back to lat/long and populate a globe like this one
http://code.google.com/p/webgl-globe/

Comment: do you want to fill with with dots of regular locations like lattice?  if so i think i saw the same Q a week ago in gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is the one I was thinking about [Create regular point grid in Postgis](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4663/create-regular-point-grid-in-postgis)

Comment: the answer is in postgis, but the idea is to create grid first, covering the extent of polygon, then keep only one that is inside polygon with `INTERSECTS(pnt, poly)`, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid GIS isn't my area of expertise, but I've got two ideas:

1. Generate a set of random points. You can use a [Point-In-Polygon](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/insidepoly/) function to determine if you're points are in the right place.
2. You can use a rectangle grid of points and use a 'resolution' to determine how many points there will be and how close. You can offset the grid positions to make them look more random if you need to. You'll check if the point inside the bounding rectangle of your polygon is inside the polygon or not.

Notice that the webgl-globe example uses a grid of points(similar to point(2)) converted to spherical coordinates.
Both ideas is kind of similar, only the points distribution differs.

You can find a roughly related implementation I did using actionscript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545874/as3-random-point-on-irregular-shape/7546764#7546764),
but I would also suggest asking on the [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) site.